# TRIGGER synax error mysql said #1303 - Can't create a trigger from within another stored routine - phpmyadmin

Tags: triggers, phpmyadmin

i have db table that name is 'autoad' , 2 columns are 'allads' and 'finished' , i want before update query execute chek if value(finished) > value(allads) then throw an exception , i used trigger for this but when pat to go in phpmyadmin give error :
mysql said #1303 - Can't create a trigger from within another stored routine

```
CREATE TRIGGER before_insert_finished BEFORE INSERT ON autoad
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   SET @CountOfCar = (SELECT allads FROM autoad)
   SET @CountOfCar2 = (SELECT finished FROM autoad
   IF @CountOfCar2>@CountOfCar THEN
ON UPDATE NO ACTION
END
```

edited :

in phpmyadmin gui just want code body, between `begin....end`, i now try :

```
BEGIN
   SET @CountOfCar = (SELECT allads FROM autoad)
   SET @CountOfCar2 = (SELECT finished FROM autoad
   IF @CountOfCar2>@CountOfCar THEN
ON UPDATE NO ACTION
END
```

error :
MySQL said: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET @CountOfCar2 = (SELECT finished FROM autoad IF @CountOfCar2>@CountOfCar ' at line 3

Answer (score 0):

When you create a trigger in the phpMyAdmin GUI, you only need to enter the body of the trigger in the Definition panel between the `BEGIN ... END` part.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLBCp.png)

Comment: thank you,but yet say error, new code edited, if you know about corretc syntax please guide me.

Comment: you are missing the `)` after `(SELECT finished FROM autoad`